# Amazon SNS push notification when app is off

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk

At this moment I am trying to create push notifications functional with node.js and aws-sdk. I created function that can sent message to user, but in some reason it sends notification only if application is turned on, and not if it's turned off. But if I try to sent notification to turned off app from S3 console it runs as it should work. do you have any ideas is it something on settings or something else? my function is really simple:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'some value', secretAccessKey: 'some     value',
region: 'us-west-2'});
var sns = new AWS.SNS();

function sentMessageToOne() {    
var params = {
    Message: 'test from node',//  required      
    MessageStructure: 'String',
    Subject: 'AWS and node',
    TargetArn: 'some value'
};
sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('in sent err');
        console.log(err, err.stack);

    } // an error occurred
    else {
        console.log(data);
    }
               // successful response
});
```

};

Comment: I don't see any reference in your code to time-to-live (ttl). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-ttl.html and a zero or very low ttl seems like it would be a likely cause of this behavior.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot , thank you for response. I tried it but unfortunately it's not help. And this setting  for another case - if device switched off, but in my case device works, only application is turned off.